# Should one binarize qualitative variables before applying a random forest?

Tags: random-forest, binning

On which of theses two kinds of sample would a Random Forest (and more precisely sklearn RandomForest algorithm) give the best results ? (Y and other_features are continuous numerical variables, and the "cat_variable" modalities are not unbalanced).

```
 Y | other_features | cat_variable
...| ...            | A
...| ...            | B
...| ...            | B
...| ...            | B
...| ...            | C
...| ...            | A



 Y | other_features | is_A | is_B | is_C |
...| ...            | 1    | 0    | 0    |
...| ...            | 0    | 1    | 0    |
...| ...            | 0    | 1    | 0    |
...| ...            | 0    | 1    | 0    |
...| ...            | 0    | 0    | 1    |
...| ...            | 1    | 0    | 0    |
```

My question intend to be quite general : I'm looking for the best practice, and I want to know if binarizing categorical variables has an interest. If this is still unclear, I would be pleased if you explain me why.

Comment: **NO, you should not**

Comment: RF is perfectly capable of handling categorical variables so there is no need for this. Also, you do not want to to create needless additional variables.

Answer (score 0):

With increased **sparsity** one-hot-encoded features are *less likely to be picked as splitting criterion* compared to numeric values ('Y' and '*other_features*').

Actually, you just need 2 bits to represent 'cat_variable':
If **is_A is 0** and **is_B is 0**, then of course **is_C is 1**. So you are introducing some sort of *redundancy* with 3 features.

Since RandomForests can handle categorical/nominal values, you can stick to '*cat_variable*' as default.

But there is no general answer. You need to find out what works best for your dataset.

Comment: Could you explain why you say that there is no general answer ? All the arguments you presented are against the 2nd sample. Why do you finish with a nuanced conclusion ?

Comment: Edit: Replaced the 'So' by 'But'.